# Redirect with apache subdomain from oher hosting (?)

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, vps, web-hosting

My requirement:
access `subdomain.example.com` where `example.com` is a shared hosting, and `subdomain` is an app (schooltool) running on port `7080`.

I tried to configure `virtualhost`, but I can not set the rules of redirection.

In the url: http://book.schooltool.org/apache.html I understand that the subdomain running on the same server, but my point is that the subdomain is actually a apache running on a VPS.

Anyone have any ideas that could help?

---

Thanks a lot!
The virtualhost was configurated like this:

```
ServerName mysubdomain.mydomain.com
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  <Proxy *>
      order allow,deny
      allow from all
      deny from none
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPreserveHost on
  RewriteEngine On

  ProxyPass / http://my_ip:7080/calendar
  ProxyPassReverse / http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com:7080/calendar

</VirtualHost>
```

But, when I access to http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com the site runs but it show the IP, something like that: http://MY_IP

How I should to set for show "mysubdomain.mydomain.com"?
Regards,
Gabriel

Answer (score 0):

On your VPS add this configuration on your VirtualHost

```
ProxyPass / http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com:7080 
ProxyPassRevers / http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com:7080
```

You should have proxy module enabled.